# send data to json file with javascript fetch api

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

i have one empty json file. I want to add json data to my json file when button is clicked. but it gives error 405. how can I do?

error:

> POST net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)

code:

```
var data={
                        method:"POST",
                        body:{
                            userId:1,
                            title:"sample title",
                            body:"sample body"
                        },
                        headers:new Headers({
                            'content-type':'application/json',
                            'dataType': 'json'
                        })
                    }

           

                    fetch("anaveri.json",data).
                    then(res=>{
                        console.log(res);
                    }).
                    catch(error=>{
                        console.log(error);
                    });
```

Comment: No, you cannot update the JSON files in this way. better use a DB. or update JSON with the help of a Node server

Comment: `'dataType': 'json'` is a value for jQuery options. It isn't an HTTP request header. You aren't using jQuery. Get rid of it.

Comment: @Quentin i deleted it i get the same error

Comment: @qeqqw — I commented it was nonsense, not that it was the cause of your problem. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70754960/19068) for how to solve the problem.

Comment: @shaedrich — One of the effects of setting `'dataType': 'json'` **as a jQuery option** is to set the `Accept` header. This isn't jQuery though, this is `fetch` which doesn't support that.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I somehow misread your comment. You're right.

Answer (score 3):

The browser isn't able to directly write data to the server's file system.

It would be a horrible security problem if it could. Google's homepage would get overwritten with some different bit of trolling every few seconds!

The browser can send an HTTP request to a URL. The server then needs to use **server side programming** to process that request.

You need to pick a programming language that your server supports (or change servers to one that supports your server-side language of choice) and write a webservice that takes the data from the request and stores it.

You *could* have it write directly to a JSON file, but that risks "fun" problems with concurrent writes so it is more typical to store the data in a database and have another webservice generate the JSON on demand.

You should consider adding some sort of tests (e.g. password authentication and data validation) to control who can insert new data  and what sort of data they can insert to avoid the aforementioned vandalism problem.

Answer (score 1):

Client-side scripting isn't allowed to change files on the server or the local file system for security reasons. Depending on what you're trying to achive, you need to do one of these things:

1. Send your data to your server via POST and your server does the saving
2. Create the file contents [blob and download it](https://randomtutes.com/2019/08/02/download-blob-as-file-in-javascript/)
3. Use [the browser's `FileSystem` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) instead of the client one's

Answer (score 0):

`405 (Method Not Allowed)` means that the resource you're querying (in this case, your json file) does not implement the method you're trying to use on it. In order to add information to your json file, you need to have some sort of a backend logic that implements a RESTful API, so that you can issue requests using JavaScript - you can't just do it with JavaScript alone.